# Time Complexity issue

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Is the time complexity for inserting the node into a Binary tree the same for both balanced and unbalanced BSTs?

Answer (score 0):

For balanced tree, insert takes O(log(n)) which is the number of nodes from the root to a leaf.

If the Tree is unbalanced it could be one long chain which means that insertion may take worst case of `n` steps, meaning O(n)

Answer (score 0):

No, the time complexities can be different, if the insertion order follows some specific pattern. I'm not going to answer it fully given the effort level shown, but consider the following:

Insert a thousand elements in a BST, from smallest to largest. How many comparisons will be needed when inserting the last one ?

Answer (score 0):

How can it be same?

It is **not same**.

For example

A BST like this

```
  5
  /\
 3  7
/\  /\
2  4 6 8
```

Here if you want to insert a node(1) you will traverse 3 nodes (5-3-2).

Now for the unbalanced case:-(the worst case scenario might be)

```
       8
      /
     7
    /
  ...
  /
 2
```

Here to insert `1` you need to traverse 7 nodes.

To avoid this skewed ness the balanced search tree was introduced. You can look into the drawback of BST and then you can look into AVL tree oor RB Tree. You will get how it differs.

For a height balanced BST the complexity for search would be `O(logn)`. But for unbalanced BST in worst case it might take `O(n)`.